# Получение данных из "такой" карты высот

Tags: алгоритм, графика

от есть такой кусок карты высот (8бит на канал)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я догадался, эти резкие скачки отвечают за разные уровни высоты. То есть, где где большая разница между светлым и голубым, там осуществляется переход между уровнями. При этом участки светлее отвечают за меньшую высоту на своем уровне.

Значит попробовал я следующим образом: на каждой строке проверять разницу между значениями красного канала на соседних пикселях. Взять к примеру константу max_dist = 180, и если разница больше max_dist , тогда засчитывать переход на следующий уровень, то же самое с переходом на предыдущий уровень при разнице меньше -max_dist.

Но это не  работает, только появляются полосы. Какие еще есть способы извлечь такие данные?

UPDATE: Оказалось все еще интереснее)

Склеив все эти кусочки получил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А это не [горизонтали (изогипсы)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B0) ? – линии с одинаковой высотой.

Comment: так здесь же виден градиент

Comment: В картинке сколько каналов задействовано? Два или один?

Comment: все три, если не считая альфа. Красный самый динамичный, gb почти не меняются

Comment: Сформулируйте, что именно вы хотите получить

Comment: данные высот, естественно

Comment: Про `edge detection` и `flood fill` слышали?

Comment: Возможно, эти линии это не высоты, а всего лишь муаровый узор. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80

Comment: Посмотрите вторую лекцию по DIP от яндекса, там как раз был построчный алгоритм выделения областей. Он, правда, заточен на области одинакового цвета, но, думаю, здесь тоже можно применить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зеленый канал определяет абсолютную высоту, хотя поделен на несколько уровней(их нужно разделять, в данном примере первый уровень в голубых областях, второй в последующей красной с зеленым области, и последний в правом нижнем углу.

Красный канал это остаток зеленого.По возвышениям 255 единиц из красного немного меньше чем 1 единица из зеленого.
Отсюда можно вывести формулу

Синий канал содержит только пару уровней возвышения зеленого (но их оказывается больше, поэтому он бесполезен, все равно нужно вручную отделять уровни)

```
elevation = level*255 + green + red/256
```